# Why Google is sending SMS messages to me?

Tags: sms, google

I have just received a SMS message... from Google (?):

[image]

What is this? Does this mean that some "bad guy" has my phone number and is playing some nice tricks with me, pretending that he is a Google? Or is this truly a Google-originating message?

Why there is a garbage in the message content? Could this be some Asian or otherwise ideographic language's characters which encoding got lost during transmission through my cellular network?

Comment: Since this looks like from Messages app (by Google), probably an SMS message to activate [the RCS service](https://jibe.google.com/) (i.e. the Chat feature) which consists of 6-digit number and sent by Google, though I don't know why the encoding is broken...